# How to alter the ID of a get result. overrride get, filter and save

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to make a model anonymous.
My model is

```
class Laddu(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.TextField()
```

I need to make it anonymous in such a way that

```
Laddu.save(owner=<owner with pk = 1>, url = "google.com")
```

will actually save

```
n = anonimusAlgo(1)
Laddu.save(owner=<owner with pk = n>, url = "google.com")
```

and so for get and filter

is there any better way for making a model anonymous?

so final result is even if some one hacks in to database, he cannot get correct data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do or why you want to do it.

Comment: So you want to save your Laddu to owner randomly right ?
Generate n by some algo and if n is a primary key in Owner table save Laddu to that owner right ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a way to link your Laddu model to a User model, such that if someone will get his hand on both tables, he/she won't be able to know, which Laddu object is related to which User object.

If this is the case, instead of the field:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

You need to have a CharField, that will be an 'encrypted' version of the User PK, something like

```
owner_pk = models.CharField()
```

and then each time you want to access the user you need to:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=decrypt(laddu_obj.owner_pk))
```

See this answer to get an idea on how to generate random keys for integer PKs:
[What is the best way to get a semi long unique id (non sequential) key for Database objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877524/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-semi-long-unique-id-non-sequential-key-for-datab)