What is an optimal way to create unique human readable values in postgres?
I have an orders table. For simplicity sake, I'll just include the columns that matters.



id
number




uuid1
ABC123


uuid2
DEF456



The number column is unique but it is not auto-generated by the database, although I hope it could. And it has to be easy to read.
Currently, I'm running a recursive function to look up the table for a number before inserting.
const generateOrderNumber = async(length) => {
  const number = generateKey(length).toUpperCase(); // random readable string with length of 6

  const exists = await pg.query(`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE number = $1`, [number]);

  if (exists.rows.length) {
    return await generateOrderNumber(length + 1);
  }

  return number;
);

const number = await generateOrderNumber(6);

await pg.query(`INSERT INTO orders (number) VALUES ($1)`, [number]);

What this function does is it will generate a string of the specified length, look up the orders number column with that string, if exists, rerun the function again with length + 1 until none returns.
Is this an optimal way to tackle this problem? Are there better solutions?

Have you already bumped into collisions with the number or is this theoretical? Do you have an unique constraint on the number column?

No, IMO it's not optimal. Is this question opinion-based or do you have a metric for "optimal"?

You could have a SERIAL column and then use a simple algorithm to map some of the digits into letters for display (or copy to another column).

Also, what exactly do you mean by "easy to read"? Three uppercase letters followed by three digits?

You could also run the uuid through a hash function and then prettify (and shorten) the result. This is more efficient and less likely to result in duplicates.

(Oh, and in any case, your current implementation is prone to TOCTOU issues.)

@AKX Yes, this is theoretical. By optimal, meaning not prone to errors like my implementation.

@Lukas Hmm, I'm interested in that hash function. Do have an example?

@Roger is there a specific format these identifiers should take? That will affect the most efficient (and safe) way of generating them.

No, just readable.

How do you define "readable"? Anyway, maybe my ancient answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878781/51685 helps here.
